# Unexpected DML in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, dml

What could have caused the following statements, a virus or an attack?

```
...
2018-06-18 16:49:07 BOT FATAL:  las conexiones restantes están reservadas a superusuarios y no de replicación
2018-06-18 16:49:44 BOT FATAL:  las conexiones restantes están reservadas a superusuarios y no de replicación
2018-06-18 16:49:44 BOT FATAL:  las conexiones restantes están reservadas a superusuarios y no de replicación
2018-06-18 16:50:31 BOT FATAL:  las conexiones restantes están reservadas a superusuarios y no de replicación
2018-06-18 16:50:31 BOT FATAL:  las conexiones restantes están reservadas a superusuarios y no de replicación
2018-06-18 16:51:18 BOT FATAL:  las conexiones restantes están reservadas a superusuarios y no de replicación
2018-06-18 16:51:19 BOT FATAL:  las conexiones restantes están reservadas a superusuarios y no de replicación
2018-06-18 17:42:28 BOT ERROR:  error de sintaxis en o cerca de «WHERE» en carácter 40
2018-06-18 17:42:28 BOT SENTENCIA:  UPDATE tab_expediente SET exp_codigo = WHERE exp_id =
2018-06-18 17:48:30 BOT ERROR:  error de sintaxis en o cerca de «WHERE» en carácter 40
2018-06-18 17:48:30 BOT SENTENCIA:  UPDATE tab_expediente SET exp_codigo = WHERE exp_id =
2018-06-18 17:53:10 BOT ERROR:  secuencia de bytes no válida para codificación «UTF8»: 0xbf
2018-06-18 17:53:11 BOT ERROR:  secuencia de bytes no válida para codificación «UTF8»: 0xf0 0x27 0x27 0xf0
2018-06-18 17:53:20 BOT ERROR:  secuencia de bytes no válida para codificación «UTF8»: 0xc0 0xaf
2018-06-18 18:03:52 BOT ERROR:  secuencia de bytes no válida para codificación «UTF8»: 0xc0 0xaf
2018-06-18 18:03:53 BOT ERROR:  secuencia de bytes no válida para codificación «UTF8»: 0xbf
2018-06-18 18:03:53 BOT ERROR:  secuencia de bytes no válida para codificación «UTF8»: 0xf0 0x27 0x27 0xf0
2018-06-18 18:05:42 BOT WARNING:  pgstat wait timeout
2018-06-18 18:24:28 BOT ERROR:  no existe el esquema «response»
2018-06-18 18:24:28 BOT SENTENCIA:  UPDATE tab_expediente SET exp_codigo =1 WHERE exp_id = response.write(9244359*9753930)
2018-06-18 18:24:28 BOT ERROR:  la sintaxis de entrada no es válida para integer: «+response.write(9244359*9753930)+» en carácter 56
2018-06-18 18:24:28 BOT SENTENCIA:  UPDATE tab_expediente SET exp_codigo =1 WHERE exp_id = '+response.write(9244359*9753930)+'
2018-06-18 18:24:29 BOT ERROR:  no existe la columna «+response.write(9244359*9753930)+» en carácter 56
2018-06-18 18:24:29 BOT SENTENCIA:  UPDATE tab_expediente SET exp_codigo =1 WHERE exp_id = "+response.write(9244359*9753930)+"
2018-06-18 18:24:29 BOT ERROR:  no existe el esquema «response»
2018-06-18 18:24:29 BOT SENTENCIA:  UPDATE tab_expediente SET exp_codigo =1 WHERE exp_id = response.write(9051224*9765629)
2018-06-18 18:24:29 BOT ERROR:  la sintaxis de entrada no es válida para integer: «+response.write(9051224*9765629)+» en carácter 56
2018-06-18 18:24:29 BOT SENTENCIA:  UPDATE tab_expediente SET exp_codigo =1 WHERE exp_id = '+response.write(9051224*9765629)+'
2018-06-18 18:24:29 BOT ERROR:  no existe la columna «+response.write(9051224*9765629)+» en carácter 56
2018-06-18 18:24:29 BOT SENTENCIA:  UPDATE tab_expediente SET exp_codigo =1 WHERE exp_id = "+response.write(9051224*9765629)+"
...
```

The last statement is executed many times.
How can I give more security to avoid this problem?

Comment: it's a bug in your application

Comment: It looks like an application bug, but it could also be a (weird) SQL injection attack.

Comment: In the application there is no such statement, it may be an SQL injection.
How and when should I go to ensure that this does not happen again?